# Chisel: How the "read" function (or macro) is implemented for the SyncReadMem class?

Tags: chisel

Can anyone help me to understand how "read" macro is implemented? I have the feeling that "do_read" function below is actually called, but could not figure out how that is done. I'm intrigued by the "SourceInfoTransform" class. Can anyone give me a hint on its usage?
The "SyncReadMem" implementation is listed below.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Best regards,

-Fei

```
sealed class SyncReadMem[T <: Data] private (t: T, n: BigInt, val readUnderWrite: SyncReadMem.ReadUnderWrite) extends MemBase[T](t, n) {
  def read(x: UInt, en: Bool): T = macro SourceInfoTransform.xEnArg

  /** @group SourceInfoTransformMacro */
  def do_read(addr: UInt, enable: Bool)(implicit sourceInfo: SourceInfo, compileOptions: CompileOptions): T = {
    val a = Wire(UInt())
    a := DontCare
    var port: Option[T] = None
    when (enable) {
      a := addr
      port = Some(read(a))
    }
    port.get
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SourceInfoTransform` is a scala macro that transforms the `def read` into the `def do_read`. The code for the macro is in `src/main/scala/chisel3/internal/sourceinfo/SourceInfoTransform.scala` of `github.com/chipsalliance/chisel3`. In that file there are a lot of transform classes for handling different chisel constructs with different numbers of arguments. The main use of the `SourceInfoTransform` is to get the line number of the Chisel/Scala source so it can be reported in Exceptions and in generated Firrtl and Verilog. Here [is an article on macros](https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/an-introduction-to-scala-macros-908ee8752bd5), there are many more available.
Good luck.

Comment: Really appreciate the hint! It suddenly started to make sense to me now.

Best regards,

-Fei

Answer (score 1):

Chick's answer is mostly correct--it's correct on the "how" and where to look, but slightly wrong on the "why":

> The main use of the SourceInfoTransform is to get the line number of the Chisel/Scala source

This is not quite true, you can get source locators with merely having `implicit sourceInfo: SourceInfo`, and you could have that on the original `def read` if you wanted to. What the `SourceInfoTransform` macros do is resolve ambiguity when you want to do a bit extraction immediately following invoking the `read` method, eg.

```scala
myMem.read(addr, en)(16, 0)
```

If we had defined `read` with the implicits directly, the compiler would think you're trying to pass `16` and `0` as the implicit arguments, when in reality, you're trying to call `.apply` on the resulting `T` (if it's a subtype of `Bits`). The macro resolves the ambiguity so that the compiler knowns you're not trying to pass the implicits.

Here's a link to a talk where I describe this (**warning** while the little part about source locators and the macro are correct, much of this talk is out-of-date): https://youtu.be/2-ZiXNd9wbc?t=2756